# sending http request over a secured connection java

Tags: java, servlets, httpwebrequest

I have .war on the server which contains servlets. When I send an HTTP request through the browser, I am able to connect and retrieve files. Now, I want to do this programmtically in Java. In order to connect, I am first sending a get request that contains the user name and the password. Now assuming that I will stay logged in, I am sending another get request with its parameters to get the file, but I am unable to retrieve the file. Is there any way to do this? Currently, I use HttpClient and HttpGet to connect and execute the get requests.

Eventually what I am trying to do is to have an application, deployed on a server call a servlet on the same server but under a .war (i.e. implemented as another application) and retrieve a file. I have tried to call the servlet directly but also I have been able to figure that out.

Comment: **"In order to connect i am first sending a get request that contains the user name and the password."** Please don't do that

Comment: you might make the resource constrained using <security-constraint> tag in the web.xml, thus in order to get the file the user should be authenticated to access that file.